# Save Pyspark Dataframe into csv without headers

Tags: export-to-csv, pyspark

I'm looking for a way to save a dataframe into a csv file without specifying headers.

I tried the code below but it did not work.

```
ratingsDF.coalesce(1).write.option("header", "false")\
.csv("csv_file_without_headers.csv")
```

For the dataframe below:

```
+---------+-----+
|   x|   y|    z|
+----+----+-----+
|   0|   a|    5|
|   1|   b|   12|
|   2|   c|    7|
|   3|   d|   27|
|   4|   e|  149|
|   5|   f|   19|
+---------+-----+
```

The expected result of csv:

```
O,a,5
1,b,12
2,c,7
3,d,27
4,e,149
5,f,19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your option looks correct and **csv files** that is getting written will **not be having headers**.

In Spark it is not possible to write to **`file`** `csv_file_without_headers.csv` instead check for `csv_file_without_headers.csv` [directory](https://kontext.tech/column/spark/357/save-dataframe-as-csv-file-in-spark).

- In the **directory you can see all the files** in the directory with out header.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
ratingsDF.coalesce(1).write.csv("/path/to/save/csv/")
```

where it will save the `csv` without header by default. You cannot specify the `csv` file name but the path only.

Comment: Thank you. Even with the code I've put, a directory named **csv_file_without_headers.csv** was created. And the csv file is inside it

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

ratingsDF.coalesce(1).write.csv("csv_file_without_headers.csv", header = False)